# How to get common values among all the column

Tags: r

I want to know which values are common among N columns, N-1 columns, N-2 columns etc.

**Input**

```
structure(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "z", "d", "b", 
   "e", "s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 
  "f"), .Dim = c(6L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "z", 
  "a")))
```

**Output**:

> ```
> common in all 4 columns :- a , b, e ,d
>
> common in maximum 3 columns :- c
>
> common in maximum 2 columns:- f,s
> ```

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, as.data.frame(df1))`  Regarding the second and third output, the logic is not clear

Comment: *common in 3 columns :- c* ... Why not `a` too? - Columns `x`, `z`, `a`

Comment: hi @akrun its not givng me result. it is printing out everything

Comment: If `l` is the object you posted, try `uniquevalues<-unique(as.vector(l))` followed by `setNames(rowSums(apply(l,2,function(x) uniquevalues %in% x)),uniquevalues)`.

Comment: @RKG It gives me `Reduce(intersect, as.data.frame(df1))#
[1] "a" "b" "d" "e"`

Comment: Because "c" is present only in that three column when i will call "a" it will be shown in all the column where it is present so it will include x,y ,z,a

Comment: But `a, c` is also present in 3 columns

Comment: its like a and c have maximum occurrence or frequency in datasheet

Comment: I don't get it...

Comment: @Sotos if you look the data , the occurence of a,b,d,e is maximun in column.  means its most common across the column. irrelavant of its position in row. So i can say a,b,d,e is present in all the four column. Next is "c" which is only common in 3 columns but not all 4 .  similary for f and s only 2 column . so least occurence across the data is f and s and most occuring value is a,b,d,e

Comment: Ok...got it. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: I have rolled back your edit because otherwise all comments and my answer would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Reshaping the given matrix from wide to long format (`melt()` has a method for matrices) and counting by value might be an approach:

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.class = TRUE)
setDT(melt(dat))[, .N, by = "value"][order(-N)]
```

> ```
>     value     N
>    <fctr> <int>
> 1:      a     4
> 2:      b     4
> 3:      d     4
> 4:      e     4
> 5:      c     3
> 6:      f     2
> 7:      s     2
> 8:      z     1
> ```

However, code needs to be enhanced to deal with duplicates in each column (`dat2` has row 1 duplicated):

```
setDT(melt(dat2))[, unique(value), by = Var2][, .N, by = "V1"][order(-N)]
```

> ```
>        V1     N
>    <fctr> <int>
> 1:      a     4
> 2:      b     4
> 3:      d     4
> 4:      e     4
> 5:      c     3
> 6:      f     2
> 7:      s     2
> 8:      z     1
> ```

or, more consisely:

```
setDT(melt(dat2))[, unique(value), by = Var2][, .N, by = "V1"][
  , toString(sort(V1)), by = N][order(-N)]
```

> ```
>        N         V1
>    <int>     <char>
> 1:     4 a, b, d, e
> 2:     3          c
> 3:     2       f, s
> 4:     1          z
> ```

`N` denotes the count of columns a value appears in.

#### Data

```
dat <- structure(
  c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "z", "d", "b", "e", "s", 
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "s", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
  .Dim = c(6L, 4L), 
  .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("x", "y", "z", "a")))

# second data set with duplicated row 1
dat2 <- dat[c(1, seq_len(nrow(dat))), ]

dat2
```

> ```
>      x   y   z   a  
> [1,] "a" "a" "a" "a"
> [2,] "a" "a" "a" "a"
> [3,] "b" "z" "b" "b"
> [4,] "c" "d" "c" "c"
> [5,] "d" "b" "d" "d"
> [6,] "e" "e" "e" "e"
> [7,] "f" "s" "s" "f"
> ```

Comment: No not with same dataset . I have given example above

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(melt(df)), , unique(value), by = df[1:103]) : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length

Comment: Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (5726).
In addition: Warning message:
In melt.data.table(df) :
  To be consistent with reshape2's melt, id.vars and measure.vars are internally guessed when both are 'NULL'. All non-numeric/integer/logical type columns are conisdered id.vars, which in this case are columns [s100.Probeset, s101.Probeset, s102.Probeset, s103.Probeset, ...]. Consider providing at least one of 'id' or 'measure' vars in future.

Comment: (1) `by = df[1:103]` is wrong after melting. You probably get an idea, when you look at the result of `melt(df)` (2) The sample data you have given in your question is a matrix with 6 rows, 4 columns and all data of the same type. Now, your production data set seems to be a data.frame or a data.table which needs to be treated differently.

Comment: Please, post a *new* question with a sample data set which is more representative of your actual data set. Thank you.

Comment: The edited data set is still a matrix not a data.frame

Comment: i got answer same like you after converting to as.matrix. can you tell me how to obtain column name which has the occuring values for example "a" is present in 4 column naming x,y,z,a similary to other as well

Comment: Concerning your additional question in your comment (which columns are those values located in), please, post a second question (according to the rules of Stack Overflow). Thank you.